# Subsonic Delete With Fluent Query Tool

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, subsonic, subsonic3

In subsonic 2 we could do this:

```
public static void DeleteTable(SubSonic.TableSchema.Table table)
{
     new Delete().From(table).Execute();
}
```

How can we do the same thing in v3? I can only seem to find documentation about using generics to target a specific table in the database...I want to be able to use it with a parameter as above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. This seems to do the trick:

```
public static void DeleteTable(DatabaseTable table)
{
     new Delete<object>(table, table.Provider).Execute();
}
```

Comment: I don't know Subsonic, but Delete<object> strikes me as wrong. Are you sure it's not Delete<DatabaseTable>(table).Execute();

Comment: This works, the problem is the designers only implemented this method for generics, I cannot use generics....because i want to make the delete....generic (ho the irony). It seems that when you use the delete overload that accepts the database table as parameter the method ignores T

Answer (score 0):

You use the SimpleRepository.DeleteMany method somehow like this

```
var repo = new SimpleRepository("ConnectionString");
repo.DeleteMany<YourClass>(x => true);
```

Or (after reading your comment) something like that

```
public static void DeleteTable(DatabaseTable table)
{
    new SubSonic.Query.Delete<object>(table, ProviderFactory.GetProvider());
}
```

The generic type "object" is used because Delete wants a Type passed, which is not used in case we create it using a table and provider.

Comment: This wont work as it will only allow me to use it for my YourClass entity, I want a method that can accept a parameter which is my database table